# when accessing the ID variable in isar Database it returns the same variable in all the data in the list

Tags: database, flutter, flutter-isar

I have a model called TransactionModel:

```
class TransactionModel {
  final Id keyID = Isar.autoIncrement;
  final DateTime dateTransaction;
  final String concept;
  final double ammountDouble;
}
```

when use:

```
print(data.keyID.toString());
```

> -9223372036854775808

but I can have more data and this always comes back;

Also, if I want to use it as an identifier for isaar's get or delete functions, it doesn't work.

in the Isar inspector if it works correctly, it shows me the data well

I hope to understand why this happens, if it is a complementary number, and how to transform it, to know why it is the same or if I am simply accessing the variable wrong.

Comment: isar version and test device name

Comment: isar: ^3.1.0+1
AVD Android 9.0  X86